# error term in nlme::lme function

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I cant seem to find this info anywhere. What do the different sides of the | in the lme or lmer (in lme4) functions represent?

i.e.,:

```
(1|ID) vs (Time|ID)
```

Essentially, why is the 1 to the left of the | and why is the ID to the right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms to the left specify components of the design matrix (as they would in any model formula), so a `1` to the left specifies an intercept, and the `Time` to the left specifies an intercept and a single numeric `Time` predictor (assuming the variable `Time` is numeric)

The terms to the right specify how many of these components exist and where. `(1|ID)` says there is different intercept for each unique value of `ID`. The term `(Time|ID)` says there is a different intercept and a different slope for `Time` for each unique value of `ID`.

*[If, for some reason, you wanted a different slope for each `ID` but not a different intercept, you would do `(-1+Time|ID)` to ask for the individual `Time` models not to have their own intercepts]*